# How to change this so that it returns arrays

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

The following code works perfectly and shows the correct output:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self expand_combinations:@"abcd" arg2:@"" arg3:3];
}

-(void) expand_combinations: (NSString *) remaining_string arg2:(NSString *)s arg3:(int) remain_depth
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        printf("%s\n",[s UTF8String]);
        return;
    }

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:s];
    for(int k=0; k < [remaining_string length]; ++k)
    {

        str = [s stringByAppendingString:[[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k] substringToIndex:1]];
        [self expand_combinations:[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k+1] arg2:str arg3:remain_depth - 1];

    }
    return;
}
```

However, instead of outputting the results, I want to return them to an NSArray. How can this code be changed to do that? I need to use the information that this function generates in other parts of my program.

Comment: It seems that you've had several questions like this. Perhaps you should check out some books about objective-c. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) has some references.

Comment: I've already read books about objective-c. You think I'll find an answer to this question in the many books that are available on objective-c? The one's I've seen don't talk about this type of problem.

Comment: Well, to be blunt, your code has multiple issues that suggest you're not well-versed in the language. So yes, reading more about Objective-C would benefit you.

Comment: Still doing it... just wow! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65703/series-of-tiny-questions-allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that you need to change in your code.

- **First** - consider changing the name of your method to something more legible and meaningful than `-expand_combinations:arg2:arg3`.
- **Second** - you have a memory leak. You don't need to set allocate memory and initialize `str` with the string `s`, because you change its value right away in the loop without releasing the old value.
- **Third** - take a look at `NSMutableArray`. At the beginning of the method, create an array with `[NSMutableArray array]`, and at every line that you have `printf`, instead, add the string to the array. Then return it.

Comment: Should I not alloc and init str, or should I just release it after the loop?

Comment: awakeFromNib: `str` is a variable. You should not allocate and init a string and assign its pointer to that variable because you assign another string's pointer to that variable immediately afterwards, both wasting and leaking the first string.

Answer (score 2):

basicaly you have:
create mutable array in `viewDidLoad` before `[self expand_combinations ...`
add aditional parameter (mutable array) to `expand_combinations`
populate array in `expand_combinations`